# Why is this set from Thomae's function finite?

Tags: real-analysis, proof-writing

Let $f(a):[0, 1] \to \mathbb{R}$ be Thomae's function, which is restated below:
$$f(a)=\begin{cases}
0 &a\text{ is irrational}\\
\frac{1}{n} &a\text{ is rational and } n \text{ is the smallest positive integer s.t. } a=\frac{m}{n} \text{ for some } m\in \mathbb{Z}^+ 
\end{cases}$$

Now consider the set $\{x \in[0, 1]:f(x) \ge \varepsilon/2\}$. Could someone please explain why this set is finite?

Comment: The possible denominators are finite (has to be $\leq 2/\epsilon$).  Each denominator only gives finitely many numerators.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $\varepsilon$ be arbitrary. By the Archimedian principle, there exists an $n\in\mathbb N$ such that $\varepsilon > \frac1n$.

Thus, if $f(a)>\varepsilon$, then $a=\frac cd$ where $c\leq d<n$. Thus, there are at most $n^2$ choices of $a$ that map to a value $>\varepsilon$.

Comment: Not important, but there seems be a $2$ in the question.

Comment: @Henry I assumed that OP would be able to see that the $2$ is irrelevant.